# Multiple named router-outlet - component imported but not initialized and rendered

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-router, angular8, router-outlet

I'm using multiple named angular 8 `router-outlet` in a web app. All the `routerLink` seems to work as it changes the URL but components in my 2nd `router-outlet` are imported but not initialized nor rendered.

---

I made a Stackblitz available here : https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-multiple-router-outlet?file=src/app/app.component.ts

As you can see, when you click on the sidebar, under photos you have a second navigation level by clicking on Google or Facebook but nothing is rendered.

In modules, components used in other modules and RouterModule are well exported to be accessible, I don't see what I've done wrong.

I tried to declare the routes with both `forRoot` and `forChild` methods, I put some logs, but I'm running out of clues.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Look at the paths in your urls when you select Facebook and Google.

Comment: Yes, it should render the right component in the right outlet no ?
I'm new to Angular 8 but seems like it's the expected behavior from the doc and all articles I've read.
For exemple : `(selection:facebook//sidebar:photos)` 
Sidebar => photos path
Selection => facebook path

Comment: @ĴošħWilliard have you more hint to give me please ?
I'm still stuck

Comment: Hi @ĴošħWilliard I changed the Stackblitz URL to https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-multiple-router-outlet?file=src/app/app.component.ts Have you a hint to give me, I'm still stuck

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Angular router is pretty simple once you understand how nested routes works there.

Let's imagine a simple configuration:

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
  { 
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
    children: [
       { path: 'child', component: ChildComponent }
    ]
  }
])
```

How would you use `router-outlet` to cover all routes above?

```
app.component.html
     \
   contains
       \
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
                 \/
             renders
                  \
              HomeComponent
             home.component.html
                  \
               contains
                    \
               <router-outlet></router-outlet>
                   renders
                       \
                     ChildComponent
```

The main takeaway here is that `router-outlet` renders component depending on router context. Once it renders component a new context is created and all `router-outlet`'s declared at this level will look at `children` configuration.

The same is true for named routes.

You've generated the link like:

```
(selection:facebook//sidebar:photos)
```

It means that these named routes should be at the same root level. But you defined `<router-outlet name="selection"></router-outlet>` at nested level inside rendered by router `LibraryComponent`.

Let's add this outlet at the same level as 'sidebar':

```
<router-outlet name="sidebar"></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="selection"></router-outlet>
```

and it actually works **[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-multiple-router-outlet-czggdz?file=src/app/sidebar/sidebar.component.html)**

---

Now let's come back to your attempt. If you want to render selection components inside `selection.component.html` then you should be using nested named routed links:

**selection.component.html**

```
[routerLink]="['.', { outlets: { selection: [routeName] } }]"
                \/
           relative path
```

The above binding will generate nested links like `(sidebar:photos/(selection:facebook))`

Now you need to move `SelectionRoutes` configuration to `children` property of `photos` path:

**selection.module.ts**

```
imports: [
  CommonModule,
  RouterModule, //.forChild(SelectionRoutes)
],
```

**sidebar.routes.ts**

```
import { SelectionRoutes } from '../selection/selection.routes';
...
export const SidebarRoutes: Route[] = [
  { path: 'photos', component: LibraryComponent, outlet: 'sidebar', children: SelectionRoutes },
```

**[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-multiple-router-outlet-qyaatp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsidebar%2Fsidebar.routes.ts)**

### Update

In order to make `facebook` as a default subroute you create a route with `redirectTo` option like:

```
export const SelectionRoutes: Route[] = [

  { path: 'facebook', component: FacebookComponent, outlet: 'selection' },
  { path: 'google', component: GoogleComponent, outlet: 'selection' },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/(sidebar:photos/(selection:facebook))', pathMatch: 'full', },
]
```

**[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-multiple-router-outlet-with-default-routes-akmdxd?file=src/app/selection/selection.routes.ts)**

Comment: Thanks a lot for your very well explained and detailed answer ! I'm gonna try the second approach hopping there won't be any issue with the relative path and my main router-outlet (not the sidebar nor selection) because it really feel weird for me to declare the router-outlet on the parent component next to sidebar router-outlet. Doesn't feel right at all :/

Comment: By the way, default routes are kind of a pain with multiple router outlets. I tried to declare a default route in the selection outlet but it doesn't seems to work : https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-multiple-router-outlet-with-default-routes?file=src%2Fapp%2Fselection%2Fselection.routes.ts

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. It works but seems not very clean / modulable to define complete strings like this :(. Not even sure it will work when adding the main routing.